# basis of the range

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I'm new here, I don't know how to write math expressions, but i'll try to make it as clear as possibile. 
I have this linear application
f:((x,y,z))=(x-y, 2x+y+z, ky+3z)
I need to find a basis for the range and kernel, for some values of k.
I write that as a matrix
1.....-1.....0
2......1.....3
0......k.....3

reducing it to the echelon's form and I get this
1.....-1.....0
0......9.....3
0......k.....3

if k=9
the matrix becomes
1.....-1.....0
0......9.....3
0......0.....0

multiplying by 1/9 the second row, you get
1.....-1.....0
0......1....1/3
0......0.....0

the basis of the range, should be {(1, 2, 0),(-1, 1, 9)} right?? the solution I have on the book is {(1, 2, 0),(0, 1, 3)}
do you guys know why??

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Each of those pairs of vectors is a basis for the same two dimensional space. You should be able to show that.

If you plan to ask or answer more questions here you should learn mathjax: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

**Edit** in response to comment.

$$
\frac{1}{3}((1, 2, 0) + (-1, 1, 9)) =  (0, 1, 3)
$$
so $(0, 1, 3)$ is in the span of $(1, 2, 0)$ and $(-1, 1, 9)$.

Now you show that $(-1, 1, 9)$ is in the span of $(1, 2, 0)$ and $(0, 1, 3)$.

Then you're done, if you understand the meaning of "basis" and have not just applied some algorithm and gotten a "different answer".

Comment: oh thank you so much! so both answers are correct?

Comment: @AndreaBurgio Yes, both are correct - and it's important that you understand why.

Comment: The dimension of the matrix is 2, meaning that any one of the vectors lies on the plane created by the linear combinations of the other 2. Consequently, if all 3 vectors lie on the same plane, only two are needed to span the plane.